# Inserting values into selected column trouble

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net

Ok, so i have been working on this for quite a while but haven't found the solution still. I am hoping you people might be able to help me.
I have this database table named Cardiology:

```
[CID]                 INT           IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
[Name]                NVARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
[Designation]         TEXT          NOT NULL,
[Qualification]       NVARCHAR (50) NULL,
[Shift]               NVARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
[Appointment_Timings] NVARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
[Ward_rounds]         NVARCHAR (50) NULL,
[Slot1]               NVARCHAR (50) NULL,
[Slot2]               NVARCHAR (50) NULL,
[Slot3]               NVARCHAR (50) NULL,
[Slot4]               NVARCHAR (50) NULL,
[BreakTime]           NVARCHAR (50) NULL,
[Slot5]               NVARCHAR (50) NULL,
[Slot6]               NVARCHAR (50) NULL,
[Slot7]               NVARCHAR (50) NULL,
[Slot8]               NVARCHAR (50) NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_Cardiology] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([CID] ASC)
```

I want to enter data into a few columns only, my query is:

```
string str = "INSERT INTO Cardiology values (@Name,@Designation,@Qualification,@Shift,@Appointment_Timings)";
            cmd = new SqlCommand(str, con);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", TextBox1.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Designation", DropDownList1.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Qualification", TextBox3.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Shift", DropDownList2.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Appointment_Timings", DropDownList3.Text);
            con.Open();
            int flag = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            if (flag == 1)    //On successful updation, shows a popup message
            {
                string msg = "Operation Successful";
                System.Text.StringBuilder sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
                sb.Append("<script type = 'text/javascript'>");
                sb.Append("window.onload=function(){");
                sb.Append("alert('");
                sb.Append(msg);
                sb.Append("')};");
                sb.Append("</script>");
                ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "alert", sb.ToString());
            }
            else if (flag == 0)
            {
                string msg1 = "Operation Unsuccessful";
                System.Text.StringBuilder sb1 = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
                sb1.Append("<script type = 'text/javascript'>");
                sb1.Append("window.onload=function(){");
                sb1.Append("alert('");
                sb1.Append(msg1);
                sb1.Append("')};");
                sb1.Append("</script>");
                ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "alert", sb1.ToString());
            }
            show1();
            con.Close();
```

`show1()` goes like this:

```
public void show1()
    {
        da = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT [CID], [Name], [Designation], [Qualification], [Shift], [Appointment_Timings] FROM [Cardiology]", con);
        da.Fill(ds);
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }
```

I have bound the DataTable through GridView so that's not an issue. I don't think so anyway. 
When i try to insert this is what is says:

> Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition.

Any kind of help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You Need to specify the columns you're entering data into if you're not inserting values into all columns e.g. `INSERT INTO Cardiology (Columns) VALUES (Values)`

Comment: Also, the TEXT type has been deprecated. You might consider using nvarchar(max) instead: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you omit the column names in the INSERT INTO syntax then you need to supply values for all columns not for just a subset of them.

You need to change your INSERT INTO commandtext to specify the names of the columns that you want to receive the values passed in by your parameters

```
 string str = @"INSERT INTO Cardiology 
                (Name, Designation,Qualification,Shift, Appointment_Timings) 
                values  
                (@Name,@Designation,@Qualification,@Shift,@Appointment_Timings)";
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide the column names that are being inserted into.

```
string str = "INSERT INTO Cardiology (Name, Designation, Qualification, Shift, Appointment_Timings) values (@Name,@Designation,@Qualification,@Shift,@Appointment_Timings)";
```

Answer (score 0):

You Need to specify the columns you're entering data into if you're not inserting values into all columns e.g. INSERT INTO Cardiology (Columns) VALUES (Values)